# Regex confusion - title of certain length

Tags: regex

I have been going through Regex tutorials for hours now and I can't seem to grasp it very well. I would like a regex statement that extracts an html title only if the title is exceptionally long (1000+ characters). I've managed to work out the following to select the entire title:

```
<title>(.*?)</title>
```

I have no idea where to begin adding the length portion. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In general, regexes are not the way to parse HTML.  See http://htmlparsing.com for an explanation why.  Here's a start: What if your `<title>`, the text, and the closing `</title>` aren't all on the same line?  That's valid HTML, but your regex won't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<title>(.{1000,})</title>
```

would do that (unless the title contains newlines - in that case it depends on the regex engine how to handle that).

This also presupposes that there is only one `<title>` tag in the string you're looking at (which probably is the case in an HTML file, so you should be OK, given the general warning that regexes are a brittle tool when dealing with HTML).

Comment: you may consider adding the "dot matches newline" switch `(?s)`

Comment: @Bohemian: Since that switch is unavailable in JavaScript, for example, I wrote in my answer that the OP needs to tell us the regex engine used.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did exactly what I needed! I'm not sure what the regex engine is on the app I'm writing this for but in any case it worked.